Long delay when Linux accesses Windows mounted shares after sleep
Our file server was upgraded from some older Windows to Windows Server, and immediately problems began to occur. The first one was that shares mounted on Linux became unavailable after wake from sleep. The Windows server admin solved that by disabling the default 15 min timeout before the connection is killed by the server. Now, the mounted shares are still available after wake from sleep, but they are inaccessible for up to several minutes. Then they work again, until Linux goes to sleep and wakes up. Is there a remedy for the several minute timeout?

Option vers=3.11 solved the issue.

Is this file manager or systemd/fstab mount? Either way you need to configure idle timeout for your shares. Otherwise the connection get abandoned by the network, while Linux still thinks it’s there. It then attempts to send packets while the connection is gone, thinking it’s there. It probably gets errors on the net which indicate that it’s a temporary failure so it just retries until it’s timeout. Then it attempts to make a new connection. To avoid this, if using the GUi file manager to mount, unmount and remount after sleep. If using database/systemd, set a timeout on your connection if it’s idle.
Example lifted from Reddit as I have no access to a PC right now:
//${SMBServer}/${share} /mnt/${ShareFolder} cifs credentials=${CredFile},vers=2.1,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,x-systemd.idle-timeout=60,uid=$UID,gid=$GID 0 0

Those options are not supported.

Ok, found it. It’s https://manpages.debian.org/testing/cifs-utils/mount.cifs.8.en.html#echo_interval=n - default interval is 60 seconds so default timeout is 2x echo internal, which means worst case scenario you may need to wait up to 3x - 180 seconds before timeout. Try changing to a more aggressive echo timeout to force more frequent checks. Note overdoing it may cause timeouts on an otherwise connected state. Setting to 5 will cause a 10-15 second delay when reconnecting after sleep.
